# IIS7: Redirect request to internal port

Tags: node.js, redirect, iis-7, port

I have a NodeJS application. I want to create a different instance of this application for each of my clients. My initial thoughts were to have each instance in a different port, and then launch a Node instance listening to those ports:

Client 1: http://client1.myapp:81  (an instance of my Node app listening port 81)

Client 2: http://client2.myapp:82  (an instance of my Node app listening port 82)

...

I wouldn't want to open so many ports externally, so I'd like to know if it's possible to have my clients accessing their apps through port 80:

Client 1: http://client1.myapp

Client 2: http://client2.myapp

...

and then have IIS redirect each request to its corresponding INTERNAL port, where the specific NodeJS app instance would be listening.

This way I only need port 80 opened externally.

Is this possible? Is this common practice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would crate only 1 app with a virtual directory for each customer. http://my_url/client1, http://my_url/client2, http://my_url/client3..... your solution will need only port 80 but it will need a DNS resolving

Comment: Sorry could you please extend your response? Ideally I'd like to use subdomains, seems more elegant when dealing with clients. If I had virtual directories, how would that resolve directing requests to each port and not having these ports opened externally? Thanks

Comment: Hello,

for whoever that might be interested: I looked into reverse proxy functionality in IIS but ended up creating simple redirect rule from http://client1.myapp to http://localhost:81

Seems that port 81 does not need to be opened externally.

If anybody sees anything wrong with this approach please let me know.

 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you suggested in your second example (sub domains).
What you will need is a valid domain and a static IP address.
You will need to add an A record (to your DNS server) to redirect all your sub domains to your IP (i.e. *.your_domain.com --> your IP address)

Then for each of your clients you will have to create a site with his header - clientX.your_domain.com

This is common practice. I also use this method to show my clients their websites.